# how to create a multi selector dropdown search box by code?

Tags: search

I need to search categories, tags, custom fields and custom taxonomies. I have to create a search box similar to this: https://www.sacconicase.it/index.php

taxonomy category+ sub category + sub-sub-category (nation- region- resort)
, so 3 select elements

taxonomy tags: Some check boxs elements (for example for air conditionings or pets allowed

custom taxonomies/custom fields for number of guests and number of bedrooms (when I set the number of guests, i.e. “3”, it’s intended I get apartments for 3 or more guests, the same for the bedrooms)

these are the basic elements to start with

My search box should stay in the right column (I have colorMag as template)

Comment: can you add the information about your custom fields and taxonomies? What do you have so far? I edited out the no plugins as recommendations are offtopic here already

Comment: @TomJNowell I added some content